# I can't set localPosition of a UI element in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've just created a label dynamically and inserted it inside a canvas. I've also set the anchors and the pivot of the label. The problem is that I can't set the localPosition. I've tried to set it to (0f,0f), but Unity3D puts it at (0f, -380f), so that it goes to the center of the screen. The code is this one:

```
GameObject label = new GameObject ("mylabel");
    label.AddComponent<Text> ();
    label.transform.SetParent(transform);
    label.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "some long text";
    label.GetComponent<Text> ().font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font;
    label.GetComponent<Text> ().fontSize = 30;
    label.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchorMin = new Vector2 (0.5f, 1f);
    label.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchorMax = new Vector2 (0.5f, 1f);
    label.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().pivot = new Vector2 (0.5f, 1f);
    label.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localPosition = new Vector2 (0f, 0f);//THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO BE WORKING, BECAUSE THE LABEL IS NOT PLACE AT (0F,0F) WHEN i RUN THE PROGRAM!!
    label.GetComponent<Text> ().color = Color.black;
    label.GetComponent<Text> ().horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Wrap;
    label.GetComponent<Text> ().verticalOverflow = VerticalWrapMode.Overflow;
    label.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (1000, 100);
```

In the code everything seems to work fine except the line where I try to set the localPosition because regardless of the value I insert I always end up seeing the label in the center of the screen.

Comment: In the parent canvas object there is no gridlayout

Comment: If you are changing `localPosition` for example to `(0f, 100f)` does label really stays at the same place?

Comment: Yes it always stays in the center

Comment: It's kinda strange because for me your code is working well. What version of Unity you are currently using? Also did you tried to create new project and execute this code there?

It would be niecly if you will post hierarchy of your objects.

Comment: I use Unity 5.1.1. I have a canvas and inside the canvas the label.

Comment: But in the inspector in the RectTransform component do I have the position or the localPosition of the UI element?

Comment: Please, execute your code in completely new Unity project and post here the results.

Also try to use `Vector3()` insted of `Vector2()` (I doubt it would help but we should try).

Comment: Because if I change the value in the inspector it works but if I want to change it via script it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, `RectTransform` is `localPosition` of object.

Comment: Also keep in mind the key differences between world position, local position, screen position and UI position, and how to convert between them. Reading up on these will prevent a lot of confusion. At least, it did for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the mistake. Instead of setting localPosition I should have set anchoredPosition, so if you take the code above and replace localPosition with anchoredPosition it works.